# How can I export DLL and Exe?

Tags: dll, unity-game-engine

I have create a game in unity . when I build the game it makes a exe file only with a big size. How can I make the dll file and a exe file that all other games have.

Answer (score 0):

When you export for Windows, you get the .exe, called [what you exported it as].exe, plus a folder called [what you exported it as]_Data.

The data folder will contain many files, including the necessary DLLs.

I assume the issue you have, is that you don't want to distribute all of those files to everyone who wants to play your game?

If so, you'll probably want to package the game into a setup.exe, so you just just send people (or have them download) the one file.

There are loads of different ways of making this file. I personally use a free one called [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which does the job fine for me.